# How do I get a field in odoo 15 from res.partner module shown in account.move?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

In odoo 15 I have created a PDF report for invoices using a custom layout via an external module. The address of the customer is specified at the top left of the first page of the PDF report. The content comes from the record that was created via "Customer" (res.partner) and selected via the field "partner_id". After the selection, the street and postal code as well as city are loaded in the edit view of an invoice and thus transferred to the PDF document.

How can I extend or overwrite the address field in my custom report layout to create an own address field that comes from the customer data (model res.partner)? I have created an additional field there via a module (address_suffix) that can store an address addition. I would like to be able to include this custom field of res.partner in the address field at account.move and in the end into the PDF report.

To illustrate it:
I want this field (address_suffix in res.partner)
[image: Field address_suffix in res.partner]

can be seen here (account.move):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the OCA [partner_address_street3](https://github.com/OCA/partner-contact/tree/15.0/partner_address_street3) module. It is similar to yours, it adds a third street field (`street3`) to store additional address information.

The module extends the address format, so it should automatically show on reports

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. I could use it as reference, because I needed a multi line field (Text) instead of a single row (Char).

Answer (score 0):

On your report xm, I think you can try using `t-field` and using widget contact inside the `t-options` tag.

**Example:**

```
<span t-field="partner_id" t-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address"]}'/>
```